# App crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 connected to an IPv6

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, alamofire, magicalrecord

I have problem with app store review. I got these messages from app store.
First review
"Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 connected to an IPv6 network when we entered Instagram account information.".

Second review
"Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 connected to an IPv6 network when we entered Instagram account information.
This occurred when your app was used: Offline"

In my app, I use Alamofire and Alamofire Object Mapper. I send request in uiwebview and then waiting to get url with access token, after that I save in Core Data with MagicalRecords. On my devices I don't have crashes.

So my part of my code which handle url on access token

```
    guard let url = url else {
        return nil
    }

    if !isRedirectURL(url) {
        return nil
    }

    let components = url.absoluteString.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
    if components.count == 2 {
        return components.last
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
```

so I check if url is redirect or no, appRedirectURL- it's redirect url from Instagram Api

```
    guard let appRedirectURL = NSURL(string: appRedirectURL) else {
        return false
    }

    //check if both urls have host
    guard let host = appRedirectURL.host, urlHost = url.host else {
        return false
    }

    return appRedirectURL.scheme == url.scheme && host == urlHost
```

Save in

At first, I tried to use tutorial to set up ipv6 on my mac
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

but in my case, I do so:

1. I connected my first iPhone and set up Personal hotspot by usb on it.
2. Share Internet from my mac with NAT64 on other device.
3. Check everything on second device.

But I don't have ipv6 on my device, which is Personal hotspot, only ipv4. Maybe, it's the problem and I should support both on first device???

So, also I have crashlogs from crashlytics, but they are very strange, they shows that I have problem in CoreData.

1. 0x1001dce94 CoreDataManager.(updateInstagramAccount(InstagramUser, completion : (Bool, NSError?) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (CoreDataManager.swift:82)
2. MagicalRecord                  0x1006b9408 __51+[MagicalRecord(Actions) saveWithBlock:completion:]_block_invoke (MagicalRecord+Actions.m:33)
3. CoreData                       0x184fa508c developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 196
4. libdispatch.dylib              0x182af147c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5. libdispatch.dylib              0x182afd4c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
6. libdispatch.dylib              0x182af4f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464

So it's my first function

```
func updateInstagramAccount(account: InstagramUser, completion: CoreDataSuccessBlock?) {
    CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.save({ (savingContext) in
        if let objectId = account.objectId, instagramAccount = InstagramAccount.createIfNeededWhereKey(InstagramAccount.Attributes.instagramId, equalTo: objectId, context: savingContext) as? InstagramAccount {

            instagramAccount.username = account.username
            instagramAccount.fullName = account.fullName
            instagramAccount.profilePictureURLPath = account.profilePictureURL?.absoluteString
            instagramAccount.website = account.website?.absoluteString
            instagramAccount.bio = account.bio
            instagramAccount.customizedBio = account.bio

            if let follows = account.counts?.follows, followedBy = account.counts?.followedBy, media = account.counts?.media {
                instagramAccount.followsCount = Int16(follows)
                instagramAccount.followedByCount = Int16(followedBy)
                instagramAccount.mediaCount = Int16(media)
            }
            instagramAccount.objectId = account.objectId
        }
    }) { (success, error) in
        completion?(success, error)
    }
}
```

I have idea that with ipv6 it has wrong mapping for InstagramUser object, but I don't know exactly and couldn't check.

Can you ask on next questions:

1. Should I have ipv6 connection on my first device to check ipv6 on the second device, if I share network with Nat64.
2. Why I have error in CoreData, instead of UIWebView delegate method.
3. What you can suggest to fix it.

**Update**
I got this url to handle access token
https://mywebsite.com/#access_token=XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Could be situation when on ipv6 I will get different url?

Comment: The IPv6 info is a red herring. The actual problem is from using your app "offline" as stated in the message about the 2nd review.

Comment: Yes, I tried in "offline", I turned off 3g, wifi and set airport mode and in results uiwebview couldn't load authorization url, but no crash in the app.

Comment: Hey den have you identified this issue coz my app rejected too.